# If HCoV-NL63 also binds to ACE2 (like SARS and SARS-CoV-2) why doesn't it cause a more severe disease (on one hand) or a pandemic (on the other)?

Tags: coronavirus, epidemiology, common-cold

By [all accounts](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7604128/) the "common cold" virus HCoV-NL63 although much further away (genetically) from SARS and SARS-CoV-2 it actually uses the same ACE2 receptor for entry (or at least the S1A spike subunit of HCoV-NL63 binds to ACE2).

So... some obvious questions stemming from that:

- Why doesn't HCoV-NL63 cause a disease as severe as SARS-CoV-2 (or SARS)? And
- Why is/was there no HCoV-NL63 pandemic?

It seems that NL63 might have some "nasty potential" though, because China [reported a 2018 outbreak](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31996093/) that did cause severe lower tract infections in infants; the virus subgenotypes
involved also showed enhanced entry in vitro compared to other NL63s. (I'm guessing this actually provides a part of the clue/answer to 1st point/question above.)

(As an interesting aside: this NL63 also targeting ACE2 seems to be a case of [parallel evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_evolution) because the S1 of HCoV-NL63 seems to be [only 10% genetically similar](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3302248/figure/F1/) to that of SARS-CoV-1. The same is true with NL63 and SARS-CoV-2; only [around](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-78506-9/figures/3) 15% similarity on S1, albeit by a different measure.)

Comment: A possible explanation is that the SARS-CoV-2 infection mechanism isn't/wasn't actually that well understood... until very recently. Apparently (Nov 2020): "NRP1 Interacts with S1 and enhances SARS-CoV-2 infection" https://science.sciencemag.org/content/370/6518/861.full although this wasn't the case for SARS and it's probably not the case for NL63 either (no cleavage site).